# XML API in jQuery ajax call: is JSONP my only option?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I'm working in jQuery and I want to query an external XML API that's on another domain, with an Ajax call.

However, my requests are being blocked because they're across domains.

How can I query this API in Ajax? Do I *have* to ask the API to start supporting JSONP or do I have any other options?

The owner of the API is friendly, so I can ask them to help - I just wondered whether JSONP is the only option.

thanks!

Comment: Why not use a proxy on your server to relay the commands/messages to the external server and then use the api? Check this link: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP is the only way to do cross-domain AJAX with jQuery unfortunately.

You can however read cross-domain with PHP and cURL, which is the same method that the Yahoo! proxy mentioned in the first comment uses. Simply make a small PHP script that uses cURL to call the API and echo out its XML response, which is in turn returned to jQuery's AJAX call.